# Assets return 404 (Not Found) error in production Yii2 framework

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2, http-status-code-404, assets

I am working on a project in Yii framework, so recently i have faced an issue with the loading of JS and CSS files. It basically returns error 404, but i am sure that the path to the files is correct. This happens only in production, on local it works fine.

Please help me out on this as i have checked all possible threads on this forum, and nothing helped me so far.

I can post screenshots for whatever you may need to help me out on this one.

EDIT: It works fine in Opera, but not on Chrome and Mozilla which makes it more confusing.

[image: Here is how it looks]

Comment: view html source in firefox.maybe path of your assets has probelm

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the path of my assets is correct.

Comment: Do you have any link for check?

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118526/discussion-between-dejan-atanasov-and-yafater).

Answer (score 1):

should check file permission first, then see the baseurl of the file path

Comment: It works fine in Opera, but not on Chrome and Mozilla, can it be related to caching issue?

Comment: i think the best way you should compare opera header from your js and css with chrome header. maybe your loaded js sending confused header to browser

Comment: I have compared, the links are the same.

Comment: For example http://mosaic.m6ltd.com/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css, this link in Chrome it returns 404, and in Opera it opens the code.

Comment: did the link you gimme not work in chrome ?? i can view it in chrome

Comment: Yes, that link isn't working in Chrome, and opens correctly in Opera.

Comment: i can open the link correctly, here i give u some css code from that link this class .xdsoft_datetimepicker

Comment: I have tried on 5 different machines, and it doesn't works in any of them.

Comment: try to open in chrome incognito , i can open the js file from that link [https://s31.postimg.org/6b4cdqu3f/testtt.png]

Comment: Wait i have tried on 3 different machines, and there it works... Can it be something with my local apache setup, because i am working this project from 3-4 machines?

Comment: do you set some virtual host in your etc host ?? or try to 'cd' to directory to see what happen you can do ls .js there. i think maybe the pointing there to ur local now , not to the server file path

Comment: I test my project mostly on Chrome and Mozilla, and never Opera. Maybe it cached the files from localhost and corrupts them when i open with production?

Comment: from the screenshoot i give to you clearly that your production loaded js is working fine , something wrong with your localhost. its weird man. hahahaha